# Did Jacques Tits have a middle name?

Tags: mathematicians

Every single web reference I have seen for [Jacques Tits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Tits) gives no indication that he had a middle name. All [except one](https://www.knaw.nl/en/members/foreign-members/4875), which suggests his initials may have been J.L..

If this is so, what was his middle name? I have not been able to discover this.

Comment: He died a couple of days ago

Comment: Jacques Leon Tits https://viaf.org/viaf/41847224/

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes I know, that is what indirectly instigated my question.

Comment: @ Rodrigo de Azevedo I would even say more: it is only in the US that people have a midname...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Generally you make a fair point, but in this case the OP specifically referred to a source which used two initials, so it seems to me a reasonable question, not a cultural assumption.

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker Other countries apart from the US have middle names.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Because I saw a reference to "J.L. Tits". The L means he has a middle name. You can call it a "second first name" if you like, but as this is an English language website I prefer to use the English term. I am not renaming the question to suit a cultural whim.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I disagree. The question is perfectly appropriate. Your general user in an English language website, when investigating details of a mathematician whose name is presented in the form "J.L. Tits" will *naturally* ask "What is that 'middle name' which begins with L?" Those nations whose first language is English overwhelmingly understand the concept of a "middle name", but far fewer will also know that (at least some) other nations do not. Hence the question asking for a "middle name" is more directly accessible (and hence "useful") than the suggested alternative.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ... It is then the business of the person answering such a question to add that information: "people from the social milieu of the subject of this question do not have middle names." Not everybody knows this fact. Mine is not the parochialism.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I assumed he had only 3 names because that was how I saw how his name was presented: "J.L. Tits". If he had more, then somewhere out there would exist a reference to him where there is *more* than three initials. This question was entirely spurred by the existence of those references to "J.L. Tits". **I just wanted to know what the L stands for.**  I care absolutely nothing for the concerns you are raise, as they are of no importance whatsoever.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Because I don't want to.

Comment: I have to admire the entirely appropriate decorum shown in these comments.

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker - I am not American, and I have a middle name (John). My son has three forenames (William Arthur Francis).

Comment: @Michael Harvey What I was meaning is a real middle name like Fitzgerald in J.F. Kennedy. I wasn't thinking to the fact of having more than one Christian/given name.

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker - John is my 'real middle name' in UK usage, and Fitzgerald was JFK's 'real middle name'. It happened to be his mother's surname prior to marriage.

Comment: @Michael Harvey I see. Thank you for making me understand a little more these issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, Belgians (and French) [do not have middle names](https://www.reddit.com/r/belgium/comments/kp2ynj/do_belgians_have_middle_names/), but they can have first names consisting of two words, or several "first names as written on legal documents" (*voornamen zoals op identificatie documenten*) that are used nowhere else, apparently. Jacques' other first name, Léon, happens to be his father's first name. Here is from [Buekenhout's Biography of Jacques Tits](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-39449-2_3) written on the occasion of him receiving the Abel prize:

> "*Jacques Léon Tits was born on August 12, 1930, in Uccle (Ukkel in Dutch) in Belgium, a southern township of Brussels. All of his publications, except one, are signed Jacques Tits and this is how I [Francis Buekenhout] will refer to him from now... Jacques’s father Léon Tits (1880–1943) was a mathematician and received his education from the Université Catholique de Louvain. His mother, Maria Louisa André (1889–1957) was a piano teacher. She used to be called Louisa, and I will do so hereafter.*"